# What is the difference between (p span) and (p > span)?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am very confused and I want to know how the code can be harmed because of the bad use of each of both `p > span`and `p span`. I am referring to the selector NOT `p` related to `span`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p span` means a `SPAN` that's anywhere inside a `P` element. In the example below, this would be `span1`, `span2`, and `span3`.

`p > span` means a `SPAN` that's an immediate child of a `P` element. In the example, it's `span1` and `span3`, but not `span2`.

If you have the elements:

```
<p>
  <span id="span1"></span>
  <div><span id="span2"></span></div>
  <span id="span3"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: The explanation is fine, but the example is a little flawed - if one were to test with the given example then both selectors would only match `#span1` because the `div` is prematurely terminating the `p`. Of course you can easily fix this by using some other inline element like `strong`.

Answer (score 4):

`p span` will target any spans that happen to be inside p elements, no matter how nested.

`p > span` will target only spans that are direct descendants of p elements.

eg.

```
<p><div><span>this will match the first but not the second</span></div></p>

<p><span>this will match both</span></p>
```